# Docker images and containers just disappeared after rebooting Windows

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

I'm using `Docker` in `Windows` (via `virtualbox`). When I restarted `Windows`, all the containers just disappeared (`docker ps -a`). When checking `virtualbox`, I see two VMs named `default`, one of them is `Inaccessible`.

**Docker machines ls shows:**

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
box       -        virtualbox   Error                                         Unknown    machine does not exist
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v19.03.5
```

Can you please help me restore my containers or at least my data?

Comment: By digging deeper I found this error in the log ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 2 of controller 'SATA'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0"

Comment: It's seems something unfixed by a unexcepted behavior found by use some VB version on Windows I took a look on this VB ticket closed by obsoleted: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8595